# Get SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import when trying to import numpy in a Cython Extension

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have a cython extension inside a package which is structured like so:

```
packagename
├── MANIFEST.in
├── packagename
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── packagename.py
│   ├── subpackage1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── subpackage1.py
│   │   └── cythonExt1.pyx
│   ├── subpackage2
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── subpackage2.py
│   │   └── cythonExt2.pyx
│   └── VERSION
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

When I try to add a line in cythonExt2.pyx which imports numpy I get the following error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
SystemError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5c4ef4d8efd3> in <module>()
      1 # Calling Functions of Interest
----> 2 import pacakge.subpackage2 as thingy
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

/home/user/anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pacakage-0.0.3-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/package/__init__.py in <module>()
     18 
     19 # the following line imports all the functions from package.py
---> 20 from .package import *
     21 import package.subpackage1
     22 import package.subpackage2

/home/user/anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/package-0.0.3-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/package/package.py in <module>()
      1 from package.subpackage1 import thingy1
----> 2 from package.subpackage2 import thingy2
      3 import numpy as _np
      4 from multiprocessing import Pool as _Pool

/home/user/anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/package-0.0.3-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/package/subpackage2/subpackage2.py in <module>()
      3 import os
----> 4 from cythonExt2 import solve as solve_cython
      5 from frange import frange
      6 
/home/user/anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/package-0.0.3-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/package/subpackage2/cythonExt2.pyx in init package.subpackge2.cythonExt2 (package/subpackage2/cythonExt2.c:6158)()
      1 cimport numpy
----> 2 import numpy
      3 cimport cython
      4 
      5 def get_z_n(n, z):

SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

If I just cimport numpy this works and I have access to the numpy C API but I cannot import the numpy python functions which I need to solve a particular problem.

Why is this and how might I fix it?

I'm wondering if there is an issue with my setup file that is causing this to not work. The cython parts of my setup.py file are like so:

```
from setuptools import setup                                                                      
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize                                                            
from Cython.Build import build_ext
extensions = [Extension(                                                                          
    name="cythonExt1",                                                                               
    sources=["package/subpackage1/cythonExt1.pyx"],                                                   
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],                                                           
    ),                                                                                            
    Extension(                                                                                    
    name="cythonExt2",                                                                           
    sources=["package/subpackage2/cythonExt2.pyx"],                                           
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],                                                           
    )                                                                                             
] 

setup(name='package',                                                                             
      ...  
      include_package_data=True,                                                                  
      packages=['package',                                                                        
                'package.subpackage1',                                                             
                'package.subpackage2',                                                         
      ],                                                                                          
      ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),                                                        
      install_requires=requirements,                                                              
)
```

Comment: Looks like your line "20" is at fault. A dot may occur only between two real names, not at the beginning. Simply remove the dot and add the parent directory to PYTHONPATH.

Comment: That's strange as the code works fine without the import numpy line in the cythonExt2.pyx file, I also do this in a couple of other packages I have written and it works fine in those. I'll try to change it and see if it fixes my issue though.

Comment: I do that line in order to import the contents of the package.py directory such that when I import the package in python I can do package.function. When I add the directory to the path and do import package I just get a recursive package.package.package.package with no functions imported.

Comment: Numpy also uses this technique to import it's core utility https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py#L159

Comment: If I cythonize my code with the `import numpy as np` line outside of my module it works correctly. If I can get the import statement to work inside my module installation it should work as expected.

Comment: Using the numpy example I replaced my `import .package import *` with the following 2 lines `from . import core` `from .core import *` and renamed package.py to core.py. It still reports the same error and points to the first line with `from . import core` on that section of the error instead of my line 20 that @guidot mentioned.

Comment: Please fix all instances of the package name. You mix package with packagename and the traceback mentions `pacakge.subpackage2` which is probably a typo from manually changing the names. What works for sure is to install the package and import with the full package name. (But of course it is a bit less convenient to develop).

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I changed the name to keep it generic and easier to understand the structure. I.e. Which is the package, which the subpackages and which the extensions.

Comment: A temporary, if inelegant, workaround for this was to pass numpy into the cython functions as an input argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that numpy was not being included properly with this setup.py file and workflow. I fixed this by changing it to be such that the cython extension is cythonized in it's own directory with it's own setup.py file into a .c file and that file is then added as a C extension in the package's setup.py file. This also has the benefit that people installing your module don't need cython as you can distribute the generated .c file with the package.

I have created this complete, but simple, example on my github [here](https://github.com/AshleySetter/HowToPackageCythonAndCppFuncs).